# Android Facebook sdk login avoiding the webview client popup and using a custom Activity with login and password

Tags: android, facebook

Could anyone guide me creating a custom login activity and passing it to facebook...i dont want the dialog pop up coming....any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure out what the login dialog is doing by [looking at the source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/).